# Create column based on matched characters from another column and set all remaining unmatched characters to specified value

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
dat <- tribble(
  ~"fragment", ~"sentence",  
  "Hello", "Hello world", 
  "test",  "This is a test",
)
```

```
> dat
  fragment sentence       
  <chr>    <chr>          
1 Hello    Hello world    
2 test     This is a test
```

I would like to generate a new column (`output`) that is the same as `sentence`, but the characters not in `fragment` are set to a specified character (e.g., "x").

The desired output looks like this:

```
  fragment sentence            output        
  <chr>    <chr>               <chr>         
1 Hello    Hello world         Hello xxxxx   
2 test     This test is a test xxxx test xx x xxxx
```

Importantly, the fragment should be matched exactly and only once. For example, the fragment "all" in the sentence "all ball" would result in "all xxxx". In this same scenario, the fragment "al" would not match anything in "all ball".

EDIT (forgot to add my attempt)

I believe a combination of `mutate` and `str_detect` or `str_replace_all` could get me there, but I've had no luck so far.

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(output = str_replace_all(sentence, fragment, "x")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little bit of regex, you can match everything except the word in `fragment` and spaces, and replace those characters with `"x"`.

```r
dat %>% 
  mutate(output = mapply(\(x, y) gsub(paste0("(", x, "| )(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|."), "x", y, perl = TRUE),
                         fragment, sentence))

  fragment sentence              output                    
1 Hello    Hello world           Hello xxxxx          
2 test     This is a test        xxxx xx x test       
3 another  This is a second test xxxx xx x xxxxxx xxxx
```

If any of `dat$fragment` constitutes the pattern:

```r
pattern = paste0(dat$fragment, collapse = "|")
dat %>% 
  mutate(output = gsub(paste0("(", pattern, "| )(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|."), "x", sentence, perl = TRUE))

  fragment sentence              output                      
1 Hello    Hello world           Hello xxxxx          
2 test     This is a test        xxxx xx x test       
3 another  This is a second test xxxx xx x xxxxxx test
```

Data (with an additional row):

```r
dat <- tribble(
  ~"fragment", ~"sentence",  
  "Hello", "Hello world", 
  "test",  "This is a test",
  "another", "This is a second test",
  "test", "test test",
  "all", "all ball",
)
```

---

**Edit:**

```r
dat %>% 
  mutate(output = mapply(\(x, y) gsub(paste0("(\\b", x, "\\b| )(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|."), "x", y, perl = TRUE),
                         fragment, sentence), 
         output2 = str_locate_all(output, fragment) %>% 
           mapply(FUN = \(x, y, z){
             if(nrow(x) > 1){
               str_sub(y, x[-1, 1], x[-1, 2]) <- strrep("x", str_length(z))
               y
             } else 
               y
           }, y = output, z = fragment))

# A tibble: 5 × 4
  fragment sentence              output                output2              
  <chr>    <chr>                 <chr>                 <chr>                
1 Hello    Hello world           Hello xxxxx           Hello xxxxx          
2 test     This is a test        xxxx xx x test        xxxx xx x test       
3 another  This is a second test xxxx xx x xxxxxx xxxx xxxx xx x xxxxxx xxxx
4 test     test test             test test             test xxxx            
5 all      all ball              all xxxx              all xxxx
```

Data for edit:

```r
dat <- tribble(
  ~"fragment", ~"sentence",  
  "Hello", "Hello world", 
  "test",  "This is a test",
  "another", "This is a second test",
  "test", "test test",
  "all", "all ball",
)
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the regular expression only match one time? For instance, if the fragment were "test" and the sentence were "test test", the ideal output would be "test xxxx".

Comment: As I add complexity to the sentence, I see that there are more edge cases that don't produce the desired output. It would be ideal if the regular expression would only match the entire word and not a fragment. For example, with the fragment "all" and a sentence "all ball", the desired output is "all ____"

Comment: You can use `\\b` to match only the word (see edit). For multiple identical words, I could not find a direct way but you can find a partial solution in my edit

Comment: I found two more cases when this answer fails. (1) if the fragment ends with a comma, e.g., "this is it," returns all x's, and (2) if the fragment contains a diacritic, e.g., "observó" returns all x's.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach to do it using `dplyr::rowwise()` and in each row we apply a custom function to each string. It might not be the most performant approach, since we have a nested loop (one within `rowwise` and another one in the `map` function), so there might be better altneratives.

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat <- tribble(
  ~"fragment", ~"sentence",  
  "Hello", "Hello world", 
  "test",  "This is a test",
)

xxx_string <- function(sent, frag) {
  
  map(unlist(strsplit(sent, " ")),
    ~ {
      if(.x != frag) {
        sub(".*", paste(rep("x", nchar(.x)), collapse = ""), .x)
      } else .x
    }) %>% 
  paste(., collapse = " ")
  
}

dat %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(output = xxx_string(sentence, fragment))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   fragment sentence       output        
#>   <chr>    <chr>          <chr>         
#> 1 Hello    Hello world    Hello xxxxx   
#> 2 test     This is a test xxxx xx x test
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is great. It works perfectly for the sample data in the example, however I noticed that it fails if the fragment contains more than one word.

Comment: Thats true and is difficult to account for since the approach uses `strsplit` which splits each string into single words. Maelis approach is much better.